# Looper.prepare() exception in custom adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

I got the exception in doInBackground method of Asynctask. I am using custom adapter and perform filtering i want to perform this filtering in Asycntask the code is running perfect without Asynctask but it take 3 to 4 seconds to perform filtering. That's why i want to use the Asynctask.
Here is my code...

```
public FarmerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Farmer> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    this.items = (ArrayList<Farmer>) objects;
    this.itemsAll = (ArrayList<Farmer>) items.clone();
    this.suggestions = new ArrayList<Farmer>();
    this.CurrentContext = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if ((this.items == null) || (position + 1 > this.items.size()))
        return convertView;

    this.CurrentItem = ((Farmer) this.items.get(position));

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) CurrentContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.farmer_list_adapter, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.farmer_list_name);
    TextView fname = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.farmer_list_fname);
    TextView cnic = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.farmer_list_cnic);

    name.setText(this.CurrentItem.getFarmerName());
    fname.setText(this.CurrentItem.getFarmerFatherName());
    cnic.setText("" + this.CurrentItem.getFarmerCNIC());

    return convertView;
}

public Filter getFilter() {

    backgroundTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.e("AsynTask", " Started");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            nameFilter = new Filter() {

                public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                    String str = ((Farmer) (resultValue)).getFarmerName();
                    return str;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {

                    ArrayList<Farmer> filteredList = (ArrayList<Farmer>) results.values;
                    ArrayList<Farmer> farmerList = new ArrayList<Farmer>();
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        clear();
                        for (Farmer f : filteredList) {
                            farmerList.add(f);
                        }
                        Iterator<Farmer> customerIterator = farmerList.iterator();
                        while (customerIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Farmer fiterator = customerIterator.next();
                            add(fiterator);
                        }
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    if (constraint != null) {
                        suggestions.clear();
                        for (Farmer farmer : itemsAll) {
                            if (farmer.getFarmerName().toLowerCase()
                                    .startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                                suggestions.add(farmer);
                            }
                        }
                        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                        filterResults.values = suggestions;
                        filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                        return filterResults;
                    } else {
                        return new FilterResults();
                    }
                }

            };


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e("AsynTask", " Ended");
        }

    }.execute();

    return nameFilter;
};
```

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: why are you use notifyDataSetChanged() in doInBackground method.?

Comment: Thanks Segi for your reply. notifyDataSetChanged() is used to updates the results.

Comment: @waqassatti looks like you are attempting to update ui form `doInbackground()`. Move that part of the code to `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove Asycntask and do your job directly in performFiltering.

i dont think that adding one level of complexity will speed your searching up

Comment: You are right but i want to show progressbar when filtering takes time so i uses Asycntask.

Comment: i can't understand where to start the progress bar and where to end in this code posted in the question.

Comment: and how do you use your filter? adapter.getFilter().filter(CharSequence) ?

Comment: No i can't do this,but i got the filtering results fine

Answer (score 1):

Try to move notifyDataSetChanged() in onPostExecute(), because methods that change UI should run in main UI thread.

Comment: yes same error 06-25 11:16:22.308: E/AndroidRuntime(5423): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 1):

You can't update any UI changes in **doInBackground()** method.

Use **onPostExecute()** method to update any UI changes.

onPostExecute will be called after doInBackground method.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.e("AsynTask", " Ended");
    }
```

Comment: and it will not work, you simply cannot execute an AsyncTask in performFiltering method